# nested ul positioned absolute under parent li

Tags: html, css

Here is html+css: http://jsfiddle.net/xgXXN/

I want to `orange` (parent li) appear OVER `green` (nested ul). The green ul HAS TO be positioned absolutely because I don't want it to stretch parent li.

I can't find solution to this :(. The best would be just css modification not HTML if it's possible.

Comment: The fiddle appears to be fine.. What is the difference you want?

Comment: I need yellow LI over green UL - it can be done with setting absolute position to yellow li but then all yellow LIs collapse horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue you are having is because you are applying the `z-index` to the `li` which is then also applying through to the child list of this li.

Try setting `position:relative` and `z-index` to the anchor instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/N62x8/

Comment: "The green ul HAS TO be positioned absolutely because I don't want it to stretch parent li."
read the whole thing

Comment: Well, my apologies for trying to help. Did you look at my example because the child ul is already absolute.
`ul.main-menu > li ul {
    position:absolute;`

Comment: Hmmm, sorry but I don't believe this can be done because the `li` inherits the `z-index` from the parent `li`.

May I ask why you need the background colour on the `li` and not the anchor?

Comment: Hmm, because I use this layout - anyway I think you are right and your solution will be the best - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
ul.main-menu > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I read the issue as an issue with `z-index` and didn't even consider that it could be as simple as a `y` positioning issue. I read _over_ as in _over the top of_. I'm curious now as to which the OP meant.

Comment: No - they Y coordinate for green is OK. I want orange be over green.